# thread handler make listener don't work

Tags: android, listener, handler

i'm trying to get user's current location via the code, the basic idea is like this:

```
public class LocationProducer extends Thread {

// Timer timer1;
LocationManager lm;
boolean gps_enabled = false;

UpdateInterface mUpdateInterface;

private Looper mThreadLooper;
private Handler mHandler;

public LocationProducer(Context context, UpdateInterface updateInterface,
        String name) {
    super(name);
    mContext = context;
    mUpdateInterface = updateInterface;
}

public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();

    if (lm == null)
        lm = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }



    if (gps_enabled) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                locationListenerGps);

    }

    Log.d(TAG, "requestLocationUpdates int thread:"
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    // timer1 = new Timer();
    // timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), MAXWAITTIME);
    mThreadLooper = Looper.myLooper();
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(GetLastLocation, MAXWAITTIME);
    Looper.loop();

}

public void quitLooper() {
    lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGPSLongTimeRun);
    lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetworkLongTimeRun);
    mThreadLooper.quit();
    // mHandler.getLooper().quit();

}

LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "get location int short time run locationlistenerGPS, in thread"
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // timer1.cancel();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(GetLastLocation);
        mUpdateInterface.update(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINUPDATETIME, MINUPDATEDISTANCE,
                locationListenerGPSLongTimeRun);
        if (network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    MINUPDATETIME, MINUPDATEDISTANCE,
                    locationListenerNetworkLongTimeRun);

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};
```

the basic idea is to get user location. i have to use looper to regist a listener in a non UI thread, but when i get handler of this loop. i found that the thread just wait,in nativePollOnce as
[image]
so if new gps location update comes ,the listener just don't work anymore.

is there any way to make the listener work again ? thank you very much.

Comment: You don't need to write your own thread for this. The LocationListener will be called when location is updated. Also,  if you want to check if GPS has been enabled or disabled, you can use Broadcast Receiver to listen to that..

Comment: thank you Milanix.  i want to have an object hold the newest location , 2or3 threads cant update it, and another 2or3 other threads can read it,so basicly it's an producer-customer problem and it has to be thread safe, so i have to use lock. the most confusing part is, if i use timer instead of creating handler of this looper ,it just work fine, but the timer can't stop.